# How can I create 2 separate plot on the same page with 2 different y variables within my function

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

So I have a dataframe of 4 variables using a for loop I would like to write a function that create 1 page for every player with the year on the x-axis and 1 graph with the vo2max on the y -axis and 1 graph with the hp on the y-axis.

At the bottom you can find the second ggplot that I tried to add to this code, but it won't work. thank you for your help.

```
tv<- data.frame(
  player = c("p1","p2","p3", "p1", "p2", "p3"),
  year = c("2010", "2010", "2010", "2015", "2015", "2015"),
  vo2max = c(50, 52, 52, 53, 54, 56),
  hp = c(100, 100, 105, 103, 102, 105)
)

vohp <- function(id){
  vohp1 <- tv %>% filter(player == id)
  ggplot(vohp1, aes(year, vo2max) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    scale_y_continuous(label = scales::number_format(accuracy = 5))+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 6, angle = 90), strip.text = element_text(size = 6))+
    ggsave(paste0("~/Desktop/rtest//", id, "testttttt.pdf"))
  
 
}

for(id in unique(tv$player)){
  vohp(id)
}


#supplemental part that was not working into the code

vohp2 <- tv %>% filter(player == id)
ggplot(vohp2, aes(year, hp, group = id)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::number_format(accuracy = 5))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 6, angle = 90), strip.text = element_text(size = 6))+
  ggsave(paste0("~/Desktop/rtest//", id, "testttttt.pdf"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Some details. You can split the dataframe in a list using `split()` by player and then set in a function the scheme plot. As you want two plots per player you can build them inside the function and using `patchwork` you can merge it. Finally, you can apply the function to create the plots avoiding loops using `lapply()`. Finally, using `pdf()` function with a loop you can create the pdf with the images I showed at the end. Here the code with the built-in function and the process:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
#Data
tv<- data.frame(
  player = c("p1","p2","p3", "p1", "p2", "p3"),
  year = c("2010", "2010", "2010", "2015", "2015", "2015"),
  vo2max = c(50, 52, 52, 53, 54, 56),
  hp = c(100, 100, 105, 103, 102, 105)
)
#List
List <- split(tv,tv$player)
#Function
myfunplot <- function(x)
{
  #Plot 1
  G1 <- ggplot(x, aes(year, vo2max,group=1)) +
           geom_point() +
           geom_line() +
           scale_y_continuous(label = scales::number_format(accuracy = 5))+
           theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 6, angle = 90),
                 strip.text = element_text(size = 6))+
    ggtitle(paste0('vo2max for ',unique(x$player)))
  #Plot 2
  G2 <- ggplot(x, aes(year, hp,group=1)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    scale_y_continuous(label = scales::number_format(accuracy = 5))+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 6, angle = 90),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 6))+
    ggtitle(paste0('hp for ',unique(x$player)))
  #Compose
  GF <- G1+G2
  return(GF)
}
#Apply
Listplot <- lapply(List, myfunplot)
#Prepare to export
pdf('Myplots.pdf',width = 14)
for(i in c(1:length(Listplot)))
{
  plot(Listplot[[i]])
}
dev.off()
```

Output in the pdf file will look like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have an idea why it says that G2 cannot be added to ggplot  `Error: Can't add G2 to a ggplot object.`      Also, where is x is coming from, thought it would be my dataset. Thank you for your help very appreciated

Comment: @pat28dh Try re starting R and run only the code from the solution. It looks like a conflict, also be sure `patchwork` is loaded!